# XML Loader - Module build failed: Error: Non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, parsing

I'm using react and webpack, based on JS.
[xml-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-loader) package to parse an XML file, any XML I put inside giving me the error:

> Module build failed: Error: Non-whitespace before the first tag. Line:
>   0 Column: 1 Char: m

No matter which one I choose.

My code is:

```
var xmlTest=require('./EnumToString.xml');
console.log(xmlTest);
```

Anyone has any ideas/other parsers? No matter which I've tried, I cannot load the file.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.screenaware.com/en/blog/xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag)

Comment: Hi,I did try but couldn't do so because I'm using react+webpack, fs.readFile not recognized for some reason..

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're using xml-loader?

Comment: var xmlTest=require('./Sample.xml');
        console.log(xmlTest);
I've added to the webpackconfig.dev/prod:
         {
             test: /\.xml$/,
             use: {
                 loader: 'xml-loader',
                 options: {
                     explicitArray: false,
                 },
             },
         },

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Comment: According to the error message there is an `m` before the first tag.  Can you show the XML file in question?

Comment: I've found the issue was related to the parser I was using, it is done and dusted.